# will putting a "send link to a friend" script on my site eventually land me on spam blacklists?

Tags: php, sharing

what is the best way to do this as i am building a coupon site and would like to have "email to a friend" as a sharing option but don't want some bot sending coupons to hundreds of people that all decide to flag as spam. what does it take to get black listed?

Comment: Add a CAPTCHA (Turing Test) to avoid getting Spammed.

Comment: ok. but what does it actually take to get black listed? does anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you can never tell exactly what is needed to end up on a blacklist. You can be blocked/blacklisted by your hoster, by a certain mail provider or by a specific AntiSPAM software and all of them continuously tweak their rules. To pick your example: If you send 100 mails to GMAIL and 50 of them will be marked as SPAM, I’m pretty sure further messages from your system will be blocked.

So if you offer an open mail form, there is definitely a risk for triggering one of these rules. If your application is safe in terms of free text injections, I think the risk is not too high. Bots will try to break in from time to time, but if they can’t inject their own message, they will consider your form worthless.

That’s no guarantee. So it’s definitely a good idea to integrate a CAPTCHA or at least limits for sending emails per time interval (per IP and general).